# view response content of ajax,flash http requests

Tags: ajax, flash, firefox-addon, httpresponse

I'm interested if there is some tool (preferably a firefox addon) that allows you to record http requests and view their response header and content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) :

> HttpFox monitors and analyzes all
>   incoming and outgoing HTTP traffic
>   between the browser and the web
>   servers.
>
> It aims to bring the functionality
>   known from tools like HttpWatch or
>   IEInspector to the Firefox browser.
>
> Information available per request
>   includes:
>   - Request and response headers
>
> - Sent and received cookies
> - Querystring parameters
> - POST parameters
> - Response body

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's firebug and webkits developer tools.

Comment: I pretty much had them installed, but they don't allow monitoring http response body

Comment: It seems that now they do, webkit developer tools does not show the payload of image uploads though

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Charles, [http://www.charlesproxy.com/](http://www.fiddler2.com/).

Charles is a stand-alone application, not a browser addon (but it has browser integration) which I personally prefer, since it can monitor http traffic also outside the browser, for example when a swf is run locally or from an IDE, or any other http traffic on your system.

If you prefer a browser addon, I believe Fiddler is quite popular, http://www.fiddler2.com/.